# Vim split overflow

Tags: split, neovim

[image]

On some files, a line (often the status line) overflows straight onto the next line, which screws up rendering until the size changes (when I close/resize a vertical split etc). This also happens regardless of whether I'm in tmux or not, to clarify. I'm using NeoVim, but I can reproduce the same behaviour in regular Vim too.

It's worse when I have airline enabled, but it still happens sometimes if I have it disabled.

The appropriate settings in my vimrc.

```
" tmux background fix
set t_Co=256

" show airline
set laststatus=2

" fix airline symbols
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:airline_theme = 'gotham'

if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
  let g:airline_symbols = {}
  let g:airline_symbols.space = "\ua0"
endif
```

I'm using urvxt, but I get the same results with gnome terminal, too. Here's the only configuration I've got for that.

```
URxvt.scrollBar: false
URxvt.font: xft:Inconsolata for Powerline:size=13:style=Medium
URxvt.boldFont: xft:Inconsolata for Powerline:size=13
URxvt.title: Terminal
```

The rest of [my dotfiles](https://github.com/danprince/dotfiles) are on Github.

Any idea what could be causing this behaviour? It's especially bad when I do a vertical split and the panes have content that overflows. Scrolling one of them causes the other to get stuck.

[image]

---

I suspect it might be something to do with the font. If I use `Inconsolata for Powerline-g` then it doesn't always overflow, but the colors are wrong.

[image]

In addition to this, none of the following CSS coloring plugins work: `ap/vim-css-color`, `skammer/vim-css-color`  and `gorodinskiy/vim-coloresque`. Colors just show up as regular syntax highlighted text.

Sometimes it overflows anyway. Here you can see the written to file message rendered over the right side of airline.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is a known bug in [neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/4195) and [vim](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/sb1jmVirXPU/mPhvDnZ-CwAJ). The problem however appears to be a lot smaller on vim, since I saw that only sometimes, while in neovim it seems to happen a lot more often with statusline highlighting plugins (e.g. airline). BTW: for airline, there is a workaround [documented](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/blob/master/doc/airline.txt#L289-L291)